# Combining Javascript and JQuery - Google map and Flickr gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, flickr

I am wanting to combine both of these on the page but unsure on how to position them in script files etc...The code should explain what I mean. Both appear to work separately but not together.

google.load("jquery", "1");

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#flickr_div').flickrGallery({
            "flickrSet" : "<?php echo $row_proProfile['flickr']; ?>",
            "flickrKey" : "f3c458322d5d26502e97f1632eXXXXX"
        });

    });


    </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#map').initMap({ 
        center : '<?php echo $row_proProfile['city']; ?>', // Plain text address, or array of latitude / longitude: [ lat , lng ]
        type: 'hybrid', // hybrid, roadmap, satellite, terain
        options: { zoom: 10, scrollwheel: true } // Any property that is defined in google.maps.MapOptions
    });
    </script>
```

Replaced the key with X's.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to post more context, and describe what exactly you mean when you say it doesn't work. What do you expect to happen? What *does* happen? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: Its in Dreamweaver and not sure how to check but it doesnt load the second. I am wondering how I combine the two scripts so that they both load. The flickr one loads but the map does not.

Comment: The second script should *probably* be wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` callback like the first one.

Comment: I suspect they are both loading, but the second relies on something with `id="map"` already being on the page. Move that script to the bottom or just copy the contents of the second script into the `$(document).ready()` function, right after the `flickrGallery()` call.

Comment: I think this line was causing the problem:

<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1");</script>

The map loads and the gallery partly does but the line of code above  doesn't allow the map to appear. Does anyone know where this line of code should go?